# Will IE9 install automatically?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-update, internet-explorer-9

Now I've installed Vista SP2, will IE9 come in the normal update channel in the next day or so, or do I have to download it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Update will show IE9 as a important update through Windows Update, but must be manually selected for installation.  I will not be automatically downloaded/installed even if your computer is configured to download and install important/critical updates.

> The automatic delivery process will
>   notify users that an update is
>   available and allow users to choose
>   whether to install Internet Explorer
>   9.

[Source Document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/gg615599)

Answer (score 1):

Install IE9 from this page

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home

Answer (score 0):

It will install automatically if Windows Update is thus configured; if it's configured to only tell you "there are updates, what do you want to do?", this is what it will do.

If you want to speed up things, you can also of course force an update check.

Comment: I did an update check. It doesn't show. Does it come as part of "Windows Updates", or as part of "Microsoft Office Updates"?

Comment: Maybe it'll come if I leave it a day or so.

Comment: It's a system update, and it's considered an "important" update, so it will always show in the main page. Unless you've hidden it before because you didn't want to install it.